# Auto-adding tags to React Components in VSCode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm doing some work in React, and want to be able to auto-expand my custom components so that I don't have to keep manually adding `<`, `/>` and `>`.

Since Emmet already expands traditional markup (`div`, `h1`, etc.) I was wondering if I could expand my own components with some plugin/setting. The `|` character represents my cursor.

**How it works right now**

```js
import Items from '../components/Items'

...
render() {
  return (
    <div>
     Ite| [Suggestions: Item] 
    </div>
  )
}
...
```

I see the suggestion, press [Tab], and it expands to this

```js
<div>
  Items|
</div>
```

**What I'm looking for**

```js
<div>
  <Items>|</Items>
</div>
```

Is there an extension or setting that I need to toggle somewhere to achieve this?

---

**EDIT**

Okay after some more working with react, I've found that Emmet will expand certain words but not others? Are my component names just edge cases or am I missing something?

[image: Working Emmet expansion]
[image: Emmet expansion not working]

Answer (score 0):

Use [Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) extension. It immediately adds the closing tag when you type in the opening tag in front.